# Using "grep" for conditional matching and printing array values in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, grep

I am trying to print or alert out the values in array alpha, which start from the letter "P". I must therefore get 2 alerts viz., Peter & Pamela. But,I am unable to get my required 2 alerts. Can someone help me out printing the two "P" starting values using grep only?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var alpha = ["Peter","Jones","Pamela"];
    $.grep(alpha,function(i,value){if (alpha[value]=="P*") {alert (alpha[value]) ;} })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are assigning in the `if` test (you use `=`). Try using `==`.

Comment: Thnx for pointing, taken care of, still unable to see alerts!

Comment: Secondarily, as adeneo alludes to, `==` doesn't do glob matching. It is a literal match.

Comment: Accepted, but can you help me, with returning required values with grep?? ;(

Comment: If you fix the if check to actually match correctly do the alerts still not fire?

Comment: I've added the correct `$.grep` function in my answer, but it still makes no sense, `$.grep` isn't supposed to be used for a simple iteration like this, that would be `each`, and for a simple indexOf filter, there would be `filter`, there's usually a very specific reason for `$.grep` and that's to remove items directly from the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why wouldn't you use an `each` loop instead, `$.grep` is for filtering the array.
To check the first letter in a string, use `indexOf` and see if the match is zero, the first letter in the string etc.

```js
var alpha = ["Peter","Jones","Pamela"];
    
$.each(alpha, function(index, item) {
    if ( item.indexOf('P') === 0 ) alert(item);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you just have to use `$.grep`, it's the same thing

```
$.grep(alpha, function(item, index) {
    if ( item.indexOf('P') === 0 ) alert(item);
});
```

It's just more overhead as `$.grep` expects a return value to filter

Comment: I've clearly mentioned, I want to do with the help of "GREP ONLY"!

Comment: And I'm telling you it's the wrong method to iterate and alert ?

Comment: Thnx, buddy - also noticed places of item & values or items reverses in case of 'each' and 'grep'! It worked !!!

Answer (score 0):

How about this `if(alpha[value].indexOf('P') == 0)`

Note that `grep` will return an array, if you will just use `alert` then you better use `each` I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use $.grep, try this:

```
$.grep(alpha, function(e,i) {return e.indexOf('P')===0;}).each(function(i,v){alert(v);});
```